# ArgumentValue vs Optional (nullabale parameter) GraphQL Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

Should I use ArgumentValue or Optional when I have a GraphQL Controller with an input parameter that can be nullable? Both approaches are valid, but what is the difference between **ArgumentValue** and **Optional**?

```
@QueryMapping
public String test(ArgumentValue<Integer> intValue) {
    return testService.getData(intValue);
}


@QueryMapping
public String test(Optional<Integer> intValue) {
    return testService.getData(intValue);
}
```